# Why is autoplay video not working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html5-video, autoplay

I have this video embedded onto my index:

```
<video style="width:100%;" muted="" autoplay="">
     <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
     <source src="video.mov" type="video/mp4" codecs="hvc1">
    </video>
```

It starts playing automatically on desktops and Android phones, even iPads but not iPhone for some reason. Why is that? Is the iPhone browser blocking it or something?

Comment: Your phone isn't in low power mode, right? Also the compliant way to set an HTML no-value attribute is `autoplay="autoplay"`

Comment: I am on a simulator. I dont own an iphone. I changed the syntax but no use.

Comment: There may be a separate setting "never autoplay video" in the privacy section, depending on the iOS version. My iPhone is too old to check, but the simulator may have it set to "on".

Comment: In that case there is nothing to do on my end. Thanks.